# Why do I have so many Celery messages with CloudAMQP on Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, rabbitmq, celery, cloudamqp

My Django site running on Heroku is using CloudAMQP to handle its scheduled Celery tasks. CloudAMQP is registering many more messages than I have tasks, and I don't understand why.

e.g., in the past couple of hours I'll have run around 150 scheduled tasks (two that run once a minute, another that runs once every five minutes), but the CloudAMQP console's Messages count increased by around 1,300.

My relevant Django settings:

```python
BROKER_URL = os.environ.get("CLOUDAMQP_URL", "")
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 1
BROKER_HEARTBEAT = None
BROKER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 30
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json',]
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 7 * 86400
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS = False
CELERY_EVENT_QUEUE_EXPIRES = 60
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = None
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
```

My Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn myproject.wsgi --log-file -
main_worker: python manage.py celery worker --beat --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat --loglevel=info
```

Looking at the Heroku logs I only see the number of scheduled tasks running that I'd expect.

The RabbitMQ overview graphs tend to look like this most of the time:

[image: RabbitMQ overview]

I don't understand RabbitMQ enough to know if other panels shed light on the problem. I don't *think* they show anything obvious that would account for all these messages.

I'd like to at least understand what the extra messages are, and then whether there's a way I can eliminate some or all of them.

Comment: You can always email support@cloudamqp.com with your username and we'll take a look at it

Comment: Thanks Carl. I get so used to using Stack Overflow I sometimes forget that some places actually have support :)

Answer (score 6):

I'had got the same error few days ago.
For those who get the same issue, CloudAMQP's **doc recommend to add some arguments** when you launch your celery :

```
--without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat
```

> "This will decrease the message rates substantially. Without these
>   flags Celery will send hundreds of messages per second with different
>   diagnostic and redundant heartbeat messages."

And indeed, **this fix the issue** so far ! And you finally get only YOUR messages sent.